# ping command doesn't work after deployment though it works locally

Tags: node.js, deployment, ping

My ping application works perfectly locally, but in deployment (Heroku), I get the error:

> Command failed: ping -c 1 google.com /bin/sh: 1: ping: not found

can you explain why? and how to fix this?

I have this in the server:

```
let {stdout, stderr} = await exec(`ping -c ${ req.body.packeges} ${req.body.url}`);
```

and the response I send to the client. so I'm doing the ping command in the server (Node.js).

backend: Node.js
Frontend: Reactjs

Thank you